# Wrong timing on multi material design lite snackbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, material-design-lite

I work on notifications that appears when an update of a Symfony entity has been successfully done, for example.

What I've done for now is here (+ jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/atierant/6e0s4rk1/15/) :

```js
var messagesTypes = {
  "notice": ["This is a green NOTICE"],
  "error": ["This is a red ERROR"],
  "warning": ["This is a yellow WARNING"],
  "info": ["This is a blue INFO"]
};

var colorType = {
  "info": {
    "class": "mdl-color--blue-400",
    "icon": "done"
  },
  "error": {
    "class": "mdl-color--red-400",
    "icon": "error"
  },
  "warning": {
    "class": "mdl-color--amber-400",
    "icon": "warning"
  },
  "notice": {
    "class": "mdl-color--green-400",
    "icon": "done"
  }
};

(function() {
  'use strict';
  var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector('#snackbar');
  var timeout = 2000;
  var actionText = 'Ok';
  var handler = function(event) {};

  // elements.forEach(element => { }) correcpond à for(var element in elements)
  // infoType est un objet qui correspond à un parcours de boucle
  Object.keys(messagesTypes).forEach(infoType => {

    // Définition de l'objet à donner à manger à la SnackBar
    var objTest = {};
    objTest = {
      class: colorType[infoType].class,
      icon: colorType[infoType].icon,
      message: messagesTypes[infoType].toString(),
      type: infoType,
      timeout: timeout,
      actionHandler: function(event) {},
      actionText: actionText
    };

    // Retrait d'une éventuelle classe existante dans la liste
    // Pour chacune des classList, si elle matche le pattern je la vire
    var re = new RegExp(/(^|\s)mdl-color--\S+/, "gi");
    for (var i = 0, len = snackbarContainer.classList.length; i < len; i++) {
      // ma classe en cours
      var currentClass = snackbarContainer.classList[i];
      // Je réalise mon test
      var result = re.test(currentClass);
      // Trace pour voir si je matche ma regex
      console.log('Je traite : ', currentClass, ' resultat ', result);
      if (result === true) {
        snackbarContainer.classList.remove(currentClass);
      }
    };

    snackbarContainer.classList.add(objTest.class);
    snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(objTest);
    /*setTimeout(function() {
      snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(objTest);
    }, 5000);*/
  });
})();


function r(f) {
  /in/.test(document.readyState) ? setTimeout('r(' + f + ')', 9) : f();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.1.1/material.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.1.1/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="snackbar" class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar">
  <div class="mdl-snackbar__text"></div>
  <button class="mdl-snackbar__action" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

Depending on the alert type sent by the server (error, warning, notice, info), I try to change the class of a Material Design Lite snackbar that appears, to change its color.

I remove the `mdl-color--{color}-*` class if it exists, and I apply a new `mdl-color` class according to the correct type.

`messageTypes` are messages such as Symfony returns (in the FlashBag system).

`colorType` are matching classes.

For each of these messages, I update the existing snack bar with class and message.

Then I call the snackbar, as documented here: https://getmdl.io/components/#snackbar-section

For now, I have timings problems. It first made all the changes to classes, and then displays weird way the snack bar with a random message and the last of the color classes.

removeClass
addClass
removeClass
addClass
removeClass
addClass
removeClass
addClass
then
display snackbar with message 1
display snackbar with message 2
display snackbar with message 3
display snackbar with message 4

How can I set in this order :

removeClass
addClass
display snackbar with message 1
removeClass
addClass
display snackbar with message 2
removeClass
addClass
display snackbar with message 3
removeClass
addClass
display snackbar with message 4

Answer (score 2):

The snackbar component has an internal queue system to handle showing multiple messages in a row. What you're code is doing logically reflects the timing results you are seeing. Your code is removing/adding classes, then pushing messages onto the queue. But,before those messages finish showing it will go onto the next message. Which the message is thrown into the internal queue and then the next one is handled in your code. Which modifies the classes again and so on.

The best thing to do here is write your own object to handle the queue and abstract away this coloring logic. That way you call `NotifierObj.show('message', 'error')` for example and it will do its own queue system and in between messages apply the right class to the snackbar for the given messages indicator level.

Comment: Thank you ! Here is what I've done, what dou you think about it ? http://jsfiddle.net/atierant/qds0p29v/